# create textarea dynamically based on count of comma separated values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this array returned by the db

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [test] => alphy,poxy,jade,auma ) )
```

Then i have used explode to separate the values

```
$options = explode(",", $test1['0']['test']);
```

the result is

```
 array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "alphy" [1]=> string(4) "poxy" [2]=> string(4) "jade" [3]=> string(4) "auma" }
```

I then count the number of the values

```
$count= substr_count($test1['0']['test'], ",")+1;
```

I then now try to create textareas dynamically based on the count and values e.g text area 1 - alphy, textarea2 - poxy ...

```
  for($i=0; $i<=$count;$i++){?>
            <textarea ><?php echo $options[$i]['test']?> </textarea>
    <?php }?>
```

The above is not doing, instead each textarea has just the first letter such as a, p, j, a instead of alphy , poxy, juma, auma.

What am i missing?

Comment: `$count= count($options);`  <-- way better

Comment: what is your code for adding the textareas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate the $options array to print out your textareas - no need to get the count.

```
$test1 = array(array('id' => 3, 'test' => 'alphy,poxy,jade,auma')); 
$options = explode(",", $test1['0']['test']);
foreach ($options as $i => $option) {
    echo '<textarea name="textarea_' . $i . '">' . $option . '</textarea>';
}
```

Of course, if you really want to use the count, you can do this:

```
$test1 = array(array('id' => 3, 'test' => 'alphy,poxy,jade,auma')); 
$options = explode(",", $test1['0']['test']);
$count = count($options);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<textarea name="textarea_' . $i . '">' . $options[$i] . '</textarea>';
}
```

Edit: Given the edits to your question, it seems you're trying to access an index ('test') on each of your options.  But once they're split into an array, they become simple strings, so no need to try to access them like arrays.

The reason you're getting the first letter is because `$x = 'alpha'; $x['test']` evaluates to `$x[0]`, which accesses the first character in the string, i.e. the `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven, I must have been going a long way with this, For simplicity and efficiency, i am going with your first suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Cheers, alphy.  I added some notes at the end.  Should give you a better explanation of the results you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks again Steven, that is understandable now clearly, ow, what if say that the array returned was in the form of an object like this Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [test] => alphy,poxy,jade,auma ) )  instead of Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [test] => alphy,poxy,jade,auma ) )

Comment: `$test1['0']->test` instead of `$test1['0']['test']`